# 403 Access Denied When POST Request

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to post request to https://satreg-api.collegeboard.org/msregadmintestcenter-prod/student/search-test-center-admins and check seat available but keep getting 403 Forbidden error

Pls help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you some sort of a authentication token. The most known method is sending a [Bearer-token](https://jwt.io/) via the headers. How to get the Token is up to you tho.